# What is the default Height of a TextBlock?

Tags: wpf, silverlight

In Silverlight and WPF, is there a default height for a TextBlock and if so, what is it?

Comment: Take in mind that the user can have a windows theme that make the texblock to have a different default height...

Comment: If you have a purpose for this question other than trivia, you don't need to be shy about it. Just write up the scenario you're looking at, the problem you're looking to solve, and someone will probably help you out.

Comment: @djdanlib I am looking for an answer and here is my purpose: I have a WPF app with TextBoxes both in Grids and in StackPanels (vertical). The ones in a StackPanel somehow get a 'default' height.  I would like to set the height of the ones in the Grid controls to match so it looks nice.

Comment: @djdanlib - Found the answer! :-) For the TextBoxes in the Grid controls, set the `VerticalAlignment="Center"` and the height gets changed to it's 'default' value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <Border BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="5">
        <TextBlock x:Name="Itself" Text="{Binding ElementName=Itself, Path=ActualHeight}" />
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Given the above XAML, with Silverlight 4, the TextBlock has a default fontsize of 11, and an ActualHeight of 16. The ActualHight shown in itself will be 0 due to the height being calculated too late.

That's assuming you don't set them, in which case they won't be defaults.

Interestingly, the exact same XAML in WPF, the height of the TextBlock fills the container it's in. In this case (for me anyway) it showed its own ActualHeight was 310. WPF didn't have the issue Silverlight had with binding to its own ActualHeight. Resizing the window changed the height. So in this case the default height could be said that its Auto (or NaN).

Comment: I just tried changing to 150% (Windows 7 - Control Panel > Appearance and Personalization > Display) and it made no difference. It was still 16 for Silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

it is 23 in VS2008. But that is not so difficult to find out...

Comment: Can you explain what you means 23

Answer (score 0):

It is not a true control but a frameworkelement. Hence it's default height is the same as the control within which it is kept.

Comment: I am looking for this answer too (for WPF).  When I use the TextBox in a StackPanel it somehow gets a 'default' height, but when it is used in a Grid control it does what you say and gets the height of the cell that it occupies.  Can you please update your answer to explain where the 'default' height is coming from when used in a StackPanel?